# Drag to open link in container tab, in Firefox

Tags: firefox, autohotkey, browser-addons, drag-and-drop, multi-account-containers

What I want: **Drag a link to a direction (left for example) then it was opened in a container tab** (I have only one container currently)

What I have:

- [Firefox beta 124](https://ftp.mozilla.org/pub/devedition/candidates/124.0b3-candidates/)
- [Violentmonkey](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/violentmonkey)
- [Glitterdrag](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/glitterdrag/) that can open link by drag it to a direction, as normal tab or private window tab
- [Autohotkey](https://www.autohotkey.com/), which I create a script that can open links in a container tab by automate the clicks, but I still want a mouse-only way to do this, when I sit in a relaxing position
- [Firefox Multi-Account Containers](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/multi-account-containers/)
- [Winspector](https://www.softpedia.com/get/Security/Security-Related/Winspector.shtml) which should inspect window messages but I can't get it works on my Windows 10 x64, even with Notepad.exe when following the steps in the [tutorial](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/v2/misc/SendMessage.htm)

Is it possible to do this with addon only? Or how to do it with third party apps?

Comment: For anyone interested, I found that glitterdrag has a [pro version](https://addons.mozilla.org/zh-CN/firefox/addon/glitterdrag-pro/) (the name might be misleading it's still open-sourced, it's Glitterdrag Rebirth actually which is rebuild from scratch with new manifest v3 (whatever that is)), it's still at very earlier development state, the settings are hard to use whilst lack some features, but it support opening links in container tab :/